# Pandas column to numpy arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
    name        day       value     time
0   MAC000002   2012-12-16  0.147   09:30:00
1   MAC000002   2012-12-16  0.110   10:00:00
2   MAC000002   2012-12-16  0.736   10:30:00
3   MAC000003   2012-12-16  0.404   09:30:00
4   MAC000003   2012-12-16  0.845   10:00:00
```

I want to convert the values only to a numpy array:

```
[[0.147, 0.110, 0.736],[0.404, 0.845 ...],...]
```

The only way I can think to do this is to pivot the dataframe then dump the values:

```
new_df = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["name"],values=["value"])
data = new_df.values()
```

However the dataset is very large and there are thousands of unique names and I cant pivot the table due to memory constraints. Is there another way to dump the values grouped by name keeping day then time ordering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going down the wrong track:

- `pd.pivot_table` won't get you what you want here, by default it gives the *mean* by group. While you want to keep all values.
- NumPy arrays only give large benefits for fixed dimensions, e.g. same number of columns for each row. Here, it appears that this may not be true: one group may have 2 values and another 3. A list of lists may be more appropriate.

I'll assume you've already sorted your dataframe by date and time. Then one solution is to use `GroupBy` + `apply` with `list`:

```
res = df.groupby('name', sort=False)['value'].apply(list).values.tolist()

print(res)

[[0.147, 0.11, 0.736], [0.40399999999999997, 0.845]]
```

You may see some performance improvement by converting `'name'` to a [categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html). Another solution is possible via `collections.defaultdict`, but this will likely be slower:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def group_apply(df):
    return df.groupby('name', sort=False)['value'].apply(list).values.tolist()

def group_dict(df):
    dd = defaultdict(list)
    for name, value in df[['name', 'value']].itertuples(index=False):
        dd[name].append(value)
    return list(dd.values())

df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

assert group_apply(df) == group_dict(df)

%timeit group_apply(df)  # 8.07 ms
%timeit group_dict(df)   # 39.1 ms
```